# How to set height for chart component to support all resolution in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

Can anybody tell How to set height for chart  component  to support all resolution in extjs

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on the container. For example, a `viewport` will always fill the browser window.

So you could use:

```
new Ext.container.Viewport({
    layout: 'fit',
    items: myChart
});
```

The chart will always be as big as the browser window.